# How can I create a CAD(Clinical Document Architecture) file in the HL7 standard to import it into apple health?

Tags: xml, healthkit, cda, applehealth

I want to create a CDA file that I can import into apple health.

I tried with some examples from [this](https://github.com/HL7/C-CDA-Examples) repo.

But nothing worked so far and I get the error ***clinical document could not be imported.***

For example I just want to import a "gernal" medical checkup or a evening medicine plan.
How would a valide importable example look like ?

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

Sample C-CDAs in this repository work: https://github.com/chb/sample_ccdas